# Ruby/Rails nested module with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a **Bar** module in the most out scope like this:

```
module Bar
  def hello
    puts('hello')
  end
end
```

and I also have another **Bar** module defined inside a **Foo** module like this:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
   def self.run
     Bar::hello
   end
  end
end
```

How can I include the **hello** method defined in the most outern **Bar** module to be used inside the **Bar** module defined inside the **Foo** module?

When trying to do this I'm getting:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `extend` top level module Bar and use `::` constant prefix to start looking in the global namespace:

```rb
module Bar
  def hello
    puts('hello from top level Bar')
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar
    extend ::Bar

    def self.run
      hello
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.run # >> hello from top level Bar
```

Or without `extend`:

```rb
module Bar
  def self.hello
    puts('hello from top level Bar')
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar

    def self.run
      ::Bar.hello
    end
  end
end

Foo::Bar.run # >> hello from top level Bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the two alternatives and for explaining about the :: constant prefix. Worked like charm!